# How do I programmatically set an Angular 2 form control to dirty?

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I mark an Angular 2 Control as dirty in my code?

When I do it like this:

```
control.dirty = true;
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot set property dirty of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should use the `markAsDirty` method, like this:

```
control.markAsDirty();
```

This will also mark all direct ancestors as dirty to maintain the model.

[Docs link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#markAsDirty-anchor)

Comment: Note that this will also work on a `FormGroup`, obviating the need to set a whack of controls independently after, say, a `patchValue({})`.

Comment: While every post I find on SO says to call markAsDirty, this successfully sets the control as dirty but does not bubble up to NgForm or FormGroup. If I inspect those objects in Chrome, their "dirty" getter still returns false. I have no idea why.

Comment: @nogridbag better late then never: `this.form.control.markAsDirty()`

Comment: Looks like `setValue` doesn't make make it dirty

Comment: its change now in 2021 to controls. but it still works.

Comment: how to set form to undirty ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you call the method from your template as:

```
<form #loginForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)"> ... </form>
```

In your login.component.ts, use the following

```
login(loginForm : any) {
    //make sure that inputs are valid
    if (loginForm.invalid) { 
      Object.keys( loginForm.controls).forEach(key => {
       loginForm.controls[key].markAsDirty();
      });
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom function to mark **all** the controls in a `FormGroup` as touched/dirty like this:

```
  markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    (<any>Object).values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.markAsDirty();  // or control.markAsTouched();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For template driven forms we can use below generic code

```
 public onSubmitForm(cardFormObject: NgForm) {
        if (!cardFormObject.valid)
            this.markAsDerty(cardFormObject);      

    }

    private markAsDerty(cardFormObject: NgForm) {
        for (var eachControl in cardFormObject.controls) {
            (<FormControl>cardFormObject.controls[eachControl]).markAsDirty();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for marking dirty all the controls inside a form

Create a utils file for forms and export from there the following function

```
/**
 * Marks all the controls and their nested controls as dirty.
 * @param abstractControls - an array of controls(can be FormControls, FormGroups or FormArrays)
 */
export function markAllControlsAsDirty(abstractControls: AbstractControl[]): void {
  abstractControls.forEach((abstractControl) => {
    if (abstractControl instanceof FormControl) {
      (abstractControl as FormControl).markAsDirty({ onlySelf: true });
    } else if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {
      markAllControlsAsDirty(
        Object.values((abstractControl as FormGroup).controls)
      );
    } else if (abstractControl instanceof FormArray) {
      markAllControlsAsDirty((abstractControl as FormArray).controls);
    }
  });
}
```

After that you can just call the function anywhere in the app like this:

```
markAllControlsAsDirty([form]);
```